# free SQL Server Index defragmentation tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Is there any free tool to Analyze SQL Server Index fragmentation and defrag them instantly ?

Comment: https://ola.hallengren.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a tool from SQL Planner. You can find Index Fragmentation quickly in elegant report and defrag that instantly in GUI mode.

SQL Server Index Defragmentation is Free Forever Utility in SQL Planner !

Watch a demo about it in you tube video [here](https://youtu.be/za_L6jUwcZ0)

Comment: Please explain it in your own words. Don't post link-dependent answers.